# Folding 3D surfaces?

Tags: geometry

We know how to fold 2D object, like in Origami. However, I recently thought about how we would fold 3D surfaces.

Since we fold paper across lines, we might fold 3D surfaces across planes. Is this accurate?

[image: Figure 1.1: My amazing drawing skills :P]

I have attempted to create an illustration of this concept, using the example of a cone folded over a plane situated halfway between the endpoints ($A$ and $B$) and perpendicular to segment $AB$.

Comment: Well, you can fold a three-dimensional figure in four dimensions. But the definition of folding you are using in both cases is different, since a fold in 2D is not a reflection but a rotation.

Comment: How is a fold a rotation? I thought that it was to simply reflect across the chosen line.

Comment: Well, it's a reflection if you fold it all the way. But if you don't, it will be a rotation.

Comment: Ah, I see. If only reflects the part being folded.